# Detect click on the inner text of the element without wrapping the text in a second element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Div which is as big as half of my page using CSS:

```
<div id="bigdiv">
     CLICK ON THIS TEXT
</div>
```

I am trying to write a javascript or jquery code which detects click on the text and not the rest of the element. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to wrap it in an span, if you want to capture clicks. Text content doesn't implement the appropriate interface to trigger events.

Comment: @JonathanSampson yeah, I am trying to find a way to do it without adding a second element (for a case specific reason)

Comment: Is there something he can do in the event handler that detects whether the position of the click is on the text?

Comment: Is this the only text in the element? Also, how is the text aligned? centered horizontally, vertically, both?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek only text in it. styling dynamic. you can choose.

Comment: The click also has to be specifically on the text?

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek yes, that is what i am trying to detect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since we cannot listen for events directly on the textNodes themselves, we have to take a more creative path to solving the problem. One thing we can do is look at the coordinates of the click event, and see if it overlaps with a textNode.

First, we'll need a small helper method to help us track whether a set of coordinates exists within a set of constraints. This will make it easier for us to arbitrarily determine if a set of x/y values are *within* the a set of dimensions:

```all
function isInside ( x, y, rect ) {
    return x >= rect.left  && y >= rect.top
        && x <= rect.right && y <= rect.bottom;
}
```

This is fairly basic. The `x` and `y` values will be numbers, and the `rect` reference will be an object with at least four properties holding the absolute pixel values representing four corners of a rectangle.

Next, we need a function for cycling through all childNodes that are textNodes, and determining whether a click event took place above one of them:

```
function textNodeFromPoint( element, x, y ) {
    var node, nodes = element.childNodes, range = document.createRange();
    for ( var i = 0; node = nodes[i], i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( node.nodeType !== 3 ) continue;
        range.selectNodeContents(node);
        if ( isInside( x, y, range.getBoundingClientRect() ) ) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

With all of this in place, we can now quickly determine if a textNode was directly below the clicked region, and get the value of that node:

```
element.addEventListener( "click", function ( event ) {
    if ( event.srcElement === this ) {
        var clickedNode = textNodeFromPoint( this, event.clientX, event.clientY );
        if ( clickedNode ) {
            alert( "You clicked: " + clickedNode.nodeValue );
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the initial condition `if ( event.srcElement ) === this` allows us to ignore click events originating from nested elements, such as an image or a span tag. Clicks that happen over textNodes will show the parent element as the `srcElement`, and as such those are the only ones we're concerned with.

You can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/ug3w2xLc/

Comment: This was a great solution. I made a slight modification to it because I had a situation where there was wrapped text inside the text node. If there was a shorter line at the end of the paragraph, it was still being detected as if I clicked on text. To solve it, inside of the textNodeFromPoint I use range.getClientRects() instead of getBoundingClientRects(). Then in isInside() I loop through each rect to see if the point is inside.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - Solution without adding wrapping element**
Doing this without a wrapping element is quite a hassle. I managed to get it to work, however this will **only work for one liners that are centered vertically AND horizontally**.

To see the HTML and CSS that goes along with this, see the 
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v8jbsu3m/3/

```
jQuery('#bigDiv').click(function(e) {
    // Get the x and y offest from the window
    margin_top = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    margin_left = jQuery(this).offset().left;

    // Get the dimensions of the element.
    height = jQuery(this).height();
    width = jQuery(this).width();

    // Retrieve the font_size and remove the px addition
    font_size = parseInt(jQuery(this).css('font-size').replace('px', ''));

    // Retrieve the position of the click
    click_x = e.pageX;
    click_y = e.pageY;

    // These variables will be used to validate the end result
    var in_text_y = false;
    var in_text_x = false;

    // Determine the click relative to the clicked element
    relative_x = click_x - margin_left;
    relative_y = click_y - margin_top;

    // Determine whether the y-coordinate of the click was in the text
    if (relative_y >= (parseFloat(height) / 2) - (parseFloat(font_size) / 2) &&
        relative_y <= (parseFloat(height) / 2) + (parseFloat(font_size) / 2))
        in_text_y = true;

    // This piece of code copies the string and places it in a invisible div
    // If this div has the same font styling and no paddings etc... it can
    // be used to get the width of the text
    text = jQuery(this).text();
    text_width = jQuery('#widthTester').html(text).width();

     // Determine whether the x-coordinate of the click was in the text
    if (relative_x >= (parseFloat(width) / 2) - (parseFloat(text_width) / 2) &&
        relative_x < (parseFloat(width) / 2) + (parseFloat(text_width) / 2))
        in_text_x = true;

    // If the x and y coordinates were both in the text then take action
    if (in_text_x && in_text_y)
        alert('You clicked the text!');
});
```

Also, this code can be optimized, since the same calculcation is done multiple times, but I thought that leaving the calculcations there better illustrated what was going on.

**Solution by adding a wrapping element**

If you put a span around the text, then you can add an onClick event handler to the span.

```
<div id="bigdiv">
     <span>CLICK ON THIS TEXT</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
jQuery('#bigdiv span').click(function() {
    jquery(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: He said "without wrapping the text in a second element".

Comment: because of case specific reasons, I can not wrap the text in another span.

Comment: If there is no element around the text, the text is just part of the div. This means only the div is in the DOM and not the standalone text, meaning it cannot listen for clicks.

Comment: @ThijsRiezebeek i honestly cant believe how well you did the calculation. simply wow.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you were looking for? Also, can you guarantee that your text will always be a one-liner. Because if not, this gets even more complex. Somehow the width of the text has to be detected, I was thinking of either using a font where each character has the same width and just multiply that width by the amount of characters, or walk through each character and somehow figure out their individual lengths. Once the width is known, the width can also be used to determine on how many lines the text is.

Comment: Edited the answer, it now provides a way to determine the width of the text and solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Quick win would be to have

```
<div id="bigdiv">
    <span id="text">TEXT HERE</span>
</div>

Script:
$('#text').on('click', function() {
   .....
});
```

Comment: because of case specific reasons, I can not wrap the text in another span.

Answer (score 1):

Let's alter the content dinamically - I will make the clicking on lala available:

```
<div id="gig">
<div id="smthing">one</div>lala
<div id="else"></div>
</div>

Script:

var htmlText = $('#gig').text(); //the big divs text


    var children = $('#gig').children(); //get dom elements so they can be ignored later

    $.each(children, function (index, child) {
        var txt = $(child).text().trim(); 
        if (txt != '') { //if a child has text in him
            htmlText = htmlText.replace(txt, 'xxx'); //replace it in the big text with xxx
        }
    });

    htmlText = htmlText.split("xxx"); //split for xxx make it arrat
    var counter = 0; //the part when the text is added
    $.each(htmlText, function (i, el) {
        htmlText[i] = el.trim();

        if (htmlText[i] != "") { //if there is something here than it's my text
            htmlText[i] = '<span id="text">' + htmlText[i] + '</span>'; //replace it with a HTML element personalized
            counter++; //mark that you have replaced the text
        } else { // if there is nothing at this point it means that I have a DOM element here
            htmlText[i] = $(children[i - counter])[0].outerHTML; //add the DOM element
        }
    });

    if (children.length >= htmlText.length) { //you might have the case when not all the HTML children were added back 
        for (var i = htmlText.length - 1; i < children.length; i++) {
            htmlText[i + 1] = $(children[i])[0].outerHTML; //add them
        }
    }

    htmlText = htmlText.join(""); //form a HTML markup from the altered stuff

    $('#gig').html(htmlText); // replace the content of the big div

    $('#text').on('click', function (data) { //add click support
        alert('ok');
    });
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/atrifan/5qc27f9c/

P.S: sorry for the namings and stuff I am a little bit tired.

Are you able to do this, is this what you are looking for?

What the code does:
  It's making only the text inside the div although the div could have other divs as well, makes only the text that has no HTML container like a div a span a p an a or something like that and alters it adding it in a span and making it available for clicking.

Comment: Care to explain what exactly is going on? I'm kind of tired too and this is pretty awful to read.

Comment: I refactored the code in the comment and also in the jsfiddle and added comments, hope it helps. Try clicking on one and aftewards on clickMe to see the output.

Comment: You can also alter forward my solution and don't add the text dinamically in a span, you can calculate the position of the text based on the children above it(you already know them before incrementing the counter, just get their height and width, and you will find out where the text is) - it has the capacity of doing so. It's as general as I could think it to match multiple use cases, with a little bit of tweeking you can achieve it better without adding the text in a html wrapper

Answer (score -5):

If you want to go straight through HTML, you can use

```
<div id="bigdiv" onclick="myFunction();">
```

and then simply apply the function afterwards in JS:

```
function myFunction(){
    //...
}
```

EDIT: sorry, if you want the text to be affected, put in `<p>` around the text or `<span>` ie.

```
<div id="bigdiv">
    <p onclick="myFuncion();"> TEXT </p>
</div>
```

Comment: And what should be in this function that tells whether he clicked on the text or not?