# How to make click event only trigger on text (not other whitespace within the same element)

Tags: javascript

I have some fixed HTML (ie. HTML I can' modify) that's just a bunch of ULs with a bunch of LIs inside.  I'd like to add a click event handler to those LIs which only triggers when the user clicks on the text inside them ... but not when they click on the whitespace to the right of the text.

The easy way to solve this would be to make the LIs only take up as much width as their content, using `display: inline-block` or `float:left`.  However, if I use either of those approaches list items that are too short wind up piling up instead of staying on their own line (even with `clear:both`).  Also, there area heading H6 tags interspersed between the ULs, and if I mess with the CSS they wind up getting separated instead of being interspersed.

So, ideally I'd like to find a pure JS approach which somehow checks whether the click happened on text or whitespace:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li =>
  li.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (!wasClickOnText(e)) return;
    // rest of click handler
});
```

Is there any technique which allows me to create a `wasClickOnText` function?

Comment: As I said, the HTML is fixed, so I can't do that.

Comment: You can wrap the text in a span using javascript.

Comment: What is preventing you from altering the HTML?

Comment: Good point: anyone want to format that as an answer?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28333327/detect-click-on-the-inner-text-of-the-element-without-wrapping-the-text-in-a-sec